# How to define this loop?

Tags: python

I want to write a program that, when the user types an integer from 1 to 7 inclusive, it prints out the corresponding day of the week. This is what I have so far. What I can't figure out is how to put that when `x` has a certain value, the program prints the string on another certain value, i.e. when the user writes `1`, the program should print str(0) which is `'MONDAY'`.

```
x = (int(input('please type a number from 1 to 7, both inclusive: ')))

days_of_the_week = ['MONDAY',
                    'TUESDAY',
                    'WEDNESDAY',
                    'THURSDAY',
                    'FRIDAY',
                    'SATURDAY',
                    'SUNDAY']

for x in range(8):
    for d in range(0,7):
        print(days_of_the_week(d))
```

Answered! I used a dictionary, and it worked better than using lists and all that loops. Thanks!

Comment: cant you just print specific index value of the array? 

print(days_of_the_week[x-1]);

Comment: you should have some kind of an error check to make sure the user hasn't entered any other number but 1 - 7 (both inclusive).

Something like this - if ( 1<=x && x>=7).. else show error

Comment: I tried the x-1 but didn't work or didn't get it right.

Comment: I would normally do an error check, but it is not specified in the assignment and actually might lead to an error

Comment: When I do a sample test, days_of_the_week = ['MONDAY','TUESDAY','WEDNESDAY','THURSDAY','FRIDAY','SATURDAY','SUNDAY']
x = 5;
print(days_of_the_week[int(x)-1]);


It works for me.

Comment: The error has more to be with how they ask you to input your code. It's not like if you could do it like you would want to, but like hot their reader would work

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of those nested loops; you don't need them at all. `list`s are accessed with square brackets, not parentheses. `list`s are 0-indexed (their first element is element number zero), so you would replace those loops with this:

```
print(days_of_the_week[x-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer this directly,

```
print(days_of_the_week[x-1])
```

would do what you want. But I would store the names in a dictionary instead:

```
days_of_the_week = {1: 'MONDAY',
                    2: 'TUESDAY',
                    3: 'WEDNESDAY',
                    4: 'THURSDAY',
                    5: 'FRIDAY',
                    6: 'SATURDAY',
                    7: 'SUNDAY',
                    }
x = int(input('Please type a number from 1 to 7, both inclusive: '))
print(days_of_the_week[x])
```

Comment: The dictionary would have keys of consecutive integers, which is basically a `list`. I don't think a dictionary is called for here.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I get what you're saying, but I think the dictionary would represent GrilledSeismic's mental model much better: They want a mapping.

Comment: And a `list` is a mapping where the keys are consecutive integers. You're emulating a `list`.

Comment: If you want to argue semantics: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-mapping.

`from collections.abc import Mapping`, `isinstance(list(), Mapping)`

Comment: There's no need to be pedantic. You know you're reinventing the wheel here.

Comment: I didn't use a dictionary because we haven't seen the, yet, I'm a little familiar with them but since we haven't seen them I didn't considered them, but I think they are a great idea

Comment: The dictionary works better, if I use x-1 it prints all of them, and with the dictionary just the one specified by the input, Thank you!

Comment: @GrilledSeismic Are you still using a loop of some kind? There's no reason for the `list` not to work.

Answer (score -1):

What you want to do here is select the day whose number corresponds to the user's input. However, arrays start at 0, and so you'll want to subtract 1 from the input to match the corresponding day. If you did not perform (x-1), then typing 1 would output : TUESDAY, since TUESDAY is element 1 in array starting at 0. (In this case MONDAY is element 0.) I won't get into the details of why these start at zero, but there is a [good reason](http://developeronline.blogspot.com/2008/04/why-array-index-should-start-from-0.html). I'm not sure what you were doing with the for loops, though.

```
x = (int(input('please type a number from 1 to 7, both inclusive: ')))

days_of_the_week = ['MONDAY', 'TUESDAY','WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY']
print(days_of_the_week[x-1])
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if( 1 <=x || x => 7)
   print(days_of_the_week[x-1]);
else:
   print("incorrect input");
```

You can format the error statement however you would like.

Comment: Nope, still not even compilable.

Comment: I wasn't writing syntax... or python code... basically just what I thought the answer should look for. but thanks.

Comment: You weren't writing syntax? What does that mean? And this is a Python question; answers should be in Python.